# How can I pass data to a customView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-custom-view

I have a customView and I make a levelization on that but when ı tried to pass level from mainActivity to my customView like

```
Bundle transporter=getIntent().getExtras();
```

eclipse said ;

The method getIntent() is undefined for the type CustomView.

I dont want to make customView for every level.I must get level from my MainActivity.

How can I do this?pls help.

Here is the my activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle selectionLevel=getIntent().getExtras();
    level=selectionLevel.getString("key");      
    setContentView(R.layout.cizme_oyunu);
    initial();
}

private void initial() {

    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkButton);
    backrounds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    cizmeView = (CizmeOyunuView) findViewById(R.id.Cizme_View);
    check.setOnClickListener(this);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        int imageResources;
        imageResources = getResources().getIdentifier("check_rakam" + i,
                "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        backrounds.add(imageResources);
    }
}
```

I am getting the level from checkBox and assign to "level" in my Activity.

After that ı want to set backround up to assigned level on customView.CustomView constructor is here.

```
public CizmeOyunuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xff00ff00);// our draw
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(50);
    myContext = context;

    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.RED);


    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_rakam0);

}
```

Comment: you have to set the custom view to activity using setContentView

Comment: Pass your parameter in CustomView Constructor.

Comment: I have done but before setting ContentView , ı must pass the level to set backround to customView.So up to level,backround will be set on the CustomView.Actually,I get the level firstly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
Bundle transporter = ((Activity)getContext()).getIntent().getExtras();
```

Comment: "Activity cannot be resolved to a type".Eclipse is not allowing that:s

Comment: It s not work,probably ı cant do it truely.I added my code to post,ıt might be more illustrative.Thanks for your attention.

Comment: ı understand it now thanks for your hep it s working now .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

fetch value from Bundle transporter = ((Activity)getContext()).getIntent().getExtras(); then pass it in custom view using constructor..then extract there and use it.

Comment: Thanks for help but this customView into a XML layout,so I dont use constructor directly in mainActivity for customview.This method can work but how can ı apply in these circumstances pls explain it.